# Read out if RadioButton is selected in other controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am currently working on JavaFX Project where i need to access an FXML Object from another class to show a ComboBox if the RadioButton is selected.

So for example I have 4 RadioButtons called

```
//First Controller
@FXML
private RadioButton radioButtonS1, radioButtonS2, radioButtonS3, radioButtonS4;
```

I have to read them out in the other Controller to set them visible my ComboBoxes are called:

```
//Second Controller
@FXML
private ComboBox comboS1A, comboS1E1, comboS1E2;

@FXML
private ComboBox comboS2A, comboS2E1, comboS2E2;

@FXML
private ComboBox comboS3A, comboS3E1, comboS3E2;

@FXML
private ComboBox comboS4A, comboS4E1, comboS4E2;
```

So how can I see in the SecondController which RadioButton is selected in the FirstController and make the CombBox visible?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of other questions/answers for this subject on StackOverflow. I recommend checking out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/51050736#51050736

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a static int variable, and this variable will contain the selected RadioButton number

```
public static int selectedCombo = -1;
```

and put these lines in the initialize method of the first controller

```
radioButtonS1.setOnAction(e->{
       selectedCombo = 0;
});

radioButtonS2.setOnAction(e->{
   selectedCombo = 1;
});
...
```

In the second controller, you need to add a switch statement like the following:

```
switch(selectedCombo) {
case 0: 
// make the 1st comboBox visible
break;
case 1: 
// make the 2nd comboBox visible
break;
...
}
```